# What is the function of dihydrofolate reductase in humans?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, enzymes

According to [StatPearls](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK539712/), **synthetic** folic acid — as an artificial dietary supplement — needs to be converted into the active form **tetrahydrofolate** (THF) by dihydrofolate reductase.

> In the cells, folic acid is reduced to THF, a biologically active
> form, in a two-step process that requires two molecules of NADPH and
> the enzyme dihydrofolate reductase (DHFR).

But naturally occurring folates — as natural constituents of the diet or derived from intestinal flora — are derivatives of tetrahydrofolate, (the active form), so the human body doesn’t need to convert them using dihydrofolate reductase.

If this is the case, why do humans have the enzyme dihydrofolate reductase?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. We find it useful if posters can support their suppositions (in this case "from what I understand") by sources, either text books or online articles. Then we can check if they have perhaps misinterpreted them. Second, we expect posters to show a little research. Have you checked what readily available web sources such as Wikipedia say about DHFR? Also notice that @user438383 has kindly corrected your spelling. However you can do that yourself by writing out your question in a word processor and switching the language preference to English.

Comment: I have now cited a source and clarified your question, which initially I had difficulty in understanding. Let me know if I have changed your meaning in any way.

Comment: Thank you @David, that's exactly what I meant. English is not my native language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The poster’s assumption that the sole role of dihydrofolate reductase (DHFR) is to convert folic acid to tetrahydrofolate is *incorrect*. The enzyme is important in at least two metabolic pathways in mammals — the degradation of phenylalanine and the synthesis of thymidine.

**Phenylalanine degradation**

The degradation of phenylalanine to tyrosine requires tetrahydrobiopterin:

[image: degradation of Phe to Tyr]

Tetrahydrobiopterin is synthesized *de novo* in mammals, the last stage being the reduction of dihydrobiopterin catalysed by **dihydrofolate reductase**:

[image: Tetrahydrobiopterin synthesis]

[Sources: Berg *et al.* Biochemistry 5e (2002) Ch.28]

**Thymidylate synthesis**

Thymidine triphosphate (dTPP) is an essential DNA precursor, and is derived from thymidylate (dTMP). This latter is formed by the methylation of dUMP using *N<sup>5</sup>,N<sup>10</sup>*-methylenetetrahydrofolate, which itself is converted to dihydrofolate. This must be reduced to tetrahydrofolate in a reaction catalysed by **dihydrofolate reductase** in order to regenerate the methylenetetrahydrofolate:

[image: dTMP synthesis cycle]

[Source: Berg *et al.* Biochemistry 5e (2002) Ch.25]

Comment: IMO, the accepted literature position is that DHFR plays no role in the _de novo_ synthesis of tetrahydrobiopterin (BH4), which is synthesized from GTP, where the final step (reduction of side-chain carbonyl groups) or steps is catalysed by [sepiapterin reductase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepiapterin_reductase).  _De Novo_ synthesis of BH4 is insensitive to methotrexate, for example. DHFR _does_ participate in a 'salvage' pathway for BH4 biosynthesis, which allows pteridines such as sepiapterin to be converted to BH4 (sepiapterin is _not_ thought to be an intermediate in BH4 biosyn)

Comment: [Biosynthesis and metabolism of tetrahydrobiopterin and molybdopterin](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2862841/)

Comment: [Biosynthesis of tetrahydrobiopterin in the presence of dihydrofolate reductase inhibitors](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/6865919/)

Comment: *** [Biosynthesis of tetrahydrobiopterin by de novo and salvage pathways in adrenal medulla extracts, mammalian cell cultures, and rat brain in vivo](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/6572916/)